# How to save initial statement of object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have object of type:

```
export interface IGroupLanguage {
  name: string;
  languages?: Language[];
}

let data = [ { "name": "Automation", "languages": [ { "Name": "English", "Lcid": 1, "RightToLeft": true, "Code": "EN", "Mapped": true } ] }, { "name": "Monitors", "languages": [ { "Name": "Russian", "Lcid": 2, "RightToLeft": true, "Code": "RU", "Mapped": true } ] } ];
```

Then I tried to filter object and return a new object:

```
 this.filteredObject = [...this.groups];
    this.filteredObject.map(item => {
      item.languages = item.languages.filter(
        lg =>
          lg.Name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) != -1 ||
          lg.Code.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) != -1
      );
    });
```

Problem is that initial object `this.groups` is changed also. How to save initial statement of object?

In result I need to have not modified object `this.groups` and filtered object  `this.filteredObject`.

I know problem because JS copy objects by reference, but I dont know how to solve it.

**Full code is:**

```
search(searchQuery: string) {
    this.filteredObject = [...this.groups];
    this.filteredObject.map(item => {
      let tempLang = [...item.languages];
      item.languages = tempLang.filter(
        lg =>
          lg.Name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) != -1 ||
          lg.Code.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) != -1
      );
    });

    console.log(this.groups);
  }


ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredObject = [...this.groups];
  }
```

As result initial object `console.log(this.groups);` is also was modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spread syntax performs a shallow copy of the object.

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Copy_an_array) on copying an array with spread syntax:

> Spread syntax effectively goes one level deep while copying an array. Therefore, it may be unsuitable for copying multidimensional arrays as the following example shows (it's the same with Object.assign() and spread syntax).

This means that if there are any objects at the top level, their reference will be copied. That is the reason for this problem.

You can use  `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` to deep clone an object. But there will be data loss if the object has `Date`s, functions, `undefined`, `Infinity`, or other complex types. More info in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/2924577).

Also, when you are not returning any values use `forEach()` instead of a `map()`.

```
this.filteredObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.groups));

filteredObject.forEach(item => {
  item.languages = item.languages.filter(lg =>
    lg.Name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery.toLocaleLowerCase()) != -1 ||
    lg.Code.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery.toLocaleLowerCase()) != -1
  );
});
```

This works for properties containing objects at any nested level.

**Live Example:**

```js
let data = [ { "name": "Automation", "languages": [ { "Name": "English", "Lcid": 1, "RightToLeft": true, "Code": "EN", "Mapped": true } ] }, { "name": "Monitors", "languages": [ { "Name": "Russian", "Lcid": 2, "RightToLeft": true, "Code": "RU", "Mapped": true } ] } ];

let searchQuery = "English";

let filteredObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

filteredObject.forEach(item => {
  item.languages = item.languages.filter(lg =>
    lg.Name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery.toLocaleLowerCase()) != -1 ||
    lg.Code.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery.toLocaleLowerCase()) != -1
  );
});


console.log(data);
console.log(filteredObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have deep copied parent array of data not nested one, can you give it a try to below way -

```
this.filteredObject = [...this.groups];
    this.filteredObject.map(item => {
      let tempLang = [...item.languages];
      item.languages = tempLang.filter(lg =>
          lg.Name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) != -1 ||
          lg.Code.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery) != -1
      );
    });
```

Comment: Is it required `this.filteredObject = [...this.groups];`?

Comment: I get still modified object ` console.log(this.groups);` after filtering

Comment: I would suggest to try in a fresh piece of file, because `...` will deep clone your object/array which is required in your use case, probably something else is causing issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to deep clone your object. If you know the structure of your object, you can create a custom deep clone function with recursiveness. Otherwise, you can use the library [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

Comment: So it is common problem in Angular/JS when needs filter objects?

Comment: My answer is generic yes. The answer of @Pardeep Jain is better for your specific problem.
This is not a problem a filter but more of clone.